# What is the intended purpose of eval in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is JavaScript’s eval() not evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)

I know, generally using `eval()` is bad practice.

But for what purpose it is existed there?

What is the correct purpose of `eval()`?

At what situation it is better to use `eval()`?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval#JavaScript

Comment: It's just misspelled `evil()`. Don't use it.

Comment: *rollseyes* eval is not necessarily evil, it all depends on what you intend to use it for and sometimes there really is no other way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/eval)**

> Evaluates a string of JavaScript code
> without reference to a particular
> object.

If you construct an arithmetic expression as a string, you can use eval to evaluate it at a later time. For example, suppose you have a variable x. You can postpone evaluation of an expression involving x by assigning the string value of the expression, say "3 * x + 2", to a variable, and then calling eval at a later point in your script.

## Be careful when using eval

eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your webpage / extension.

Comment: +1 This answer seems OK to me so I upvoted it. Whoever downvoted should explain why.

Comment: Is the downvote for "Don't use eval"?

Comment: I don't know but there was a strange downvote on the answer. It seems to have gone now.

Comment: I didn't downvote it but I think the voter probably didn't like the unnecessary emphasis on not using eval. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil

Comment: I don't like absolutes like "Don't use eval!". eval is a tool. Use it when you need that specific tool, don't use it any other time. The trick is to learn the proper definition of "need".

Comment: The proper definition is just below the emphasized line.

Comment: @Bryan: couldn't have put it better myself.

Comment: @phoenix: Much better :)

Comment: You say *"You can postpone evaluation of an expression involving x by assigning the string value of the expression, say "3 * x + 2", to a variable, and then calling eval at a later point in your script."* I think creating a function to be executed later that multiplies its argument by three and adds two would be preferable to using `eval`.

Answer (score 10):

`eval()` provides access to the JavaScript compiler and this ultimately allows for code to be executed at a later time. The arguments passed to the function are passed to the JavaScript compiler after which the code is executed.

Developers argue about the security of `eval()`. It *is* less secure, but if you're absolutely sure your input is sanitized before passing it along, then it shouldn't be a problem.

Also, the results of `eval()` are generally slower because the code has not yet been compiled nor cached. There's obviously going to be a performance hit for using the function.

It's also difficult to debug code that results from the use of `eval()` because there is little-to-no contextual information (think line numbers) about the code that is ultimately executed.

In terms of web development, one of the current most popular uses of `eval()` is to deserialize a JSON string *usually* in the context of Ajax applications; however, this isn't to say that there aren't many other uses.

Comment: I like this answer the best - No BS, just an intelligently written answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5169823.html), below is a direct quote from the page which sums up the power of eval.

> The JavaScript EVAL command can be
>   very powerful when using dynamic
>   content in Web-based applications.
>   EVAL can reduce code and eases
>   interaction with data that is unknown
>   at load time, but there are drawbacks
>   to take into account.
>
> The real power of this command is its
>   ability to work with data that is not
>   known at load time—for example,
>   user-entered data. As I have
>   mentioned, EVAL takes any string that
>   you provide and executes it returning
>   a result, if one is applicable. You
>   can use this to execute JavaScript
>   where what you are being asked to
>   execute is not known at load time. For
>   example if we have a calculation
>   script that takes an equation provided
>   by the user and returns a result, you
>   can use EVAL to perform the
>   calculation.

Comment: It's `eval`, not `EVAL`.

Comment: Oh really?! It's a quote. Send your complaints to the author.

Comment: I'm aware it's a quote, but you have chosen to quote it in your answer. I'm sure no-one's really going to be confused by the capitalization in the context of this question but it's an odd way to present the name of a function in a language in which function names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's so much bad to use it as dangerous. People say don't use `eval` because it opens loopholes for abuse. It's OK to use it if your input is safe. It is used in [Doug Crockford's JSON parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js), for example, after the input has been checked using a regular expression to make sure there is no "dangerous" content.

The other reason people tell you not to use it is that if you use eval too much, people will start calling you Eval Knievel.

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting recently with the `eval()` command while trying to come up with a new convention for a new project.

What I wanted was this: I liked the idea of having **private**, **public**, and **privileged** methods, ala. [Doug Crockford's article](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html), but I wanted to be able to expose public methods/variables at the TOP of my classes instead of at the bottom as is usual.

Consider this:

```
var Singleton = function() {
    // Private
    function _one() {
        // code...
    }

    function _two() {
        // code...
    }

    // Public
    return {
        one: _one,
        two: _two
    };
}();
```

With three `eval()`'s (two nested inside of the main one) I was able to have this syntax:

```
var Singleton = function() {
    // Public
    var $interface = {
        one: $forward,
        two: $forward
    };

    // Private
    function _one() {
        // code...
    }

    function _two() {
        // code...
    }

    // This does the magic
    return eval($init);
}('Singleton');
```

And against all odds and common-sense it did work. (Note that I also wanted a way to debug my namespaces which is why you can see a string passed to the singleton. `$init` took care of this too.)

Anyway, I guess the point of typing all this is to say that `eval()` isn't necessarily the diseased runt of the JavaScript litter that should be avoided at all costs, and can be used in more ways than just on (trusted!) code sent from a server and JSON de-serializing.

(Although in my case it ended up as a mental-workout, as I had since convinced myself not to bother with private-methods/variables after all and just use a strict namespacing convention.)