# what's the purpose of eval function?

Tags: javascript

i know this function gets a string of valid JavaScript expression or statements and evaluate the expression or execute the statements, but why we need to pass code to a function for execution instead of simply writing the code in the script?

Comment: for example for using json in browser don't have the json-object. Or for calculating some input.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594023/what-is-the-intended-purpose-of-eval-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have functions: `makeCheckbox()`, `makeRadio()` and `makeSelect()` (theoretically). You want to call function by user's activity (for example menu click). You can make it with `if`, `else if` and so on, you can make `switch`, but you can `eval` too and make something like:

```
eval('make'+userChoose.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+string.slice(1)+'()');
```

where `userChoose` is one of the options: `radio`,`checkbox` or `select`, which is [first-char-uppercased](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript) first and then concatenated with `make` (before) and `()` (after), which at the end calls one of the functions.

This is not good practice because in large projects you can't simply find callings to function, because they're "hidden behind" `eval`, but sometimes it's the only way.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes code is constructed dynamically, or it's something like JSON that needs to be evaluated in the current context, etc. Doing so isn't necessarily good, or necessary--a different discussion.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on situation where you need to create dynamic variables or even parse json data. Whatever the case, it is highly recommended **NOT** to use it.

See more explanation at:

- [Exploring Javascript's eval() Capabilities And Closure Scoping](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1926-Exploring-Javascript-s-eval-Capabilities-And-Closure-Scoping.htm)

To avoid it, see;

- [Workarounds for JavaScript "eval"](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=13979)