# Accessing the value of a concatenated variable name

Tags: javascript, html, variables, concatenation

### Description of Problem:

I'm attempting to streamline some code, except that I'm obviously just creating a string instead of accessing the value of the respective variable(s). How can I convert **`'total_' + animal`** into a variable that I can then access to dynamically assign results to the DIVs?

### Code:

**JS:**

```
function tallyAnimals(animal) {
    total_animal++;
    if (animal == "dog")  { total_dog++;  }
    if (animal == "cat")  { total_cat++;  }
    if (animal == "bird") { total_bird++; }
    if (animal == "fish") { total_fish++; }

    //The problem line
    $('#' + animal).html('total_' + animal);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="animals">

    <div id="dog">0</div>
    <div id="cat">0</div>
    <div id="bird">0</div>
    <div id="fish">0</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since 'total_'+animal looks global, without eval :

```
var function tallyAnimals(animal) {
    total_animal++;
    if (animal == "dog")  { total_dog++;  }
    if (animal == "cat")  { total_cat++;  }
    if (animal == "bird") { total_bird++; }
    if (animal == "fish") { total_fish++; }

    //The problem line
    $('#' + animal).html(window['total_' + animal]);
}

should work
```

EDIT :

Ideally , you shouldnt use global variables though, and attach 'total'+animal variables to a  precise scope.

ex :

somewhere up in the file outside the function tallyAnimal:

```
var totals = {
   dog:0,
   cat:0,
   ...
}
```

so you can write

```
$('#' + animal).html(totals[animal]);
```

Comment: Is it preferred to use a global variable in this manner as opposed to eval()? Which is better practice?

Comment: eval is evil ! my point is unless you have a specific use case, you should not use eval, since you can resolve variable names dynamically according to their scope. I'm not saying that using a global variable is good though , but i'ts better than eval.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **eval()** function. Here is the solution:

```
function tallyAnimals(animal) {
    total_animal++;
    if (animal == "dog")  { total_dog++;  }
    if (animal == "cat")  { total_cat++;  }
    if (animal == "bird") { total_bird++; }
    if (animal == "fish") { total_fish++; }

    $('#' + animal).html(eval('total_' + animal));
}
```

Eval is made for this kind of work! You can also use less lines by doing this:

```
function tallyAnimals(animal) {
    total_animal++;
    eval("total_"+animal."++");
    $('#' + animal).html(eval('total_' + animal));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was told to avoid using eval() at all costs. Is this one of those rare exceptions?

Comment: Building variables with eval can be dangerous because it can be used in a malicious way... You can read some more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594023/what-is-the-intended-purpose-of-eval-in-javascript

Comment: I see. I think unless I understand it completely and thoroughly, I should probably shy away from it. Though you claim this is precisely what it was made for, so that piques my curiosity. :-) Thank you again.